# Product are going out of stock automatically

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

We are experience the issue that some products are going automatically out of stock although they have their quantity available in the product inventory section. We didn't have any customization in our theme or modify the core We have installed the M2e Pro ebay sync extension and ask them if any this is causing any sycn operation but they said there is no such operation added in M2E pro.

If any one having and experience with such type of issue kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

By default products go out of stock automatically if they reach 0 quantity and don't return to in stock when new stock is added. You can solve this by making the stock property 'Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock' a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using M2e Pro (Amazon Sync) and have a similar problem although in my case qty is actually changed to 0.

Weird thing is this extension was not being used and therefore their profiles were disabled.

Magento CE-1.9.0.1